# Random tag appeared in a span - </center>

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I have a <span> in my code and i am using it for javascript code. But suddenly </center> tag appeared in my code. I am created a function to display how many users are online. PHP and Javascript codes are added below...........................................................................

[image]

My index.php code:

```
<nav class="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <!-- Navbar Brand-->
    <a class="navbar-brand ps-3" href="index.php">CMS Admin</a>
    <!-- Sidebar Toggle-->
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i
                class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
    <!-- Navbar Search-->
    <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
        <!--                <div class="input-group">-->
        <!--                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />-->
        <!--                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>-->
        <!--                </div>-->
    </form>
    <!-- Navbar-->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">


        <!--                <a class="nav-link" href="">Users Online: --><?php //echo users_online(); ?><!--</a>-->

        <a class="nav-link" href="">Users Online:<span class="usersonline"></span></a>

        <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php">Home</a>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
               aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i> <?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="profile.php">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Activity Log</a></li>
                <li>
                    <hr class="dropdown-divider"/>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../includes/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>


</nav>
```

My js code:

```
function loadUsersOnline() {
    $.get("functions.php?onlineusers=result", function (data) {
        $(".usersonline").text(data);
    });
}

setInterval(function () {
    loadUsersOnline();
},500);
```

My functions.php code:

```
function users_online()
{

    if (isset($_GET['onlineusers'])) {

        global $connection;

        if (!$connection) {
            session_start();

            include "../includes/db.php";

            $session = session_id();
            $time = time();
            $time_out_in_seconds = 60;
            $time_out = $time - $time_out_in_seconds;

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE session = '$session'";
            $send_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($send_query);

            if ($count == NULL) {
                mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users_online(session, time) VALUES('$session', '$time')");
            } else {
                mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users_online SET time = '$time' WHERE session = '$session'");
            }


            $users_online_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE time > '$time_out'");
            echo $users_count = mysqli_num_rows($users_online_query);
        }
    } // get req
}

users_online();
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is the return of `functions.php?onlineusers=result`?

Comment: it returned 1  in the functions.php

Comment: Look at the **generated** HTML, the one the browser sees (in Firefox and Chrome that's typically Ctrl+U for the main document, and you can use the "Net" tab, response pane, for AJAX calls). My guess is that you're getting some HTML-formatted error message.

Comment: odd, but you should be using json, then it will error instead of dumping a bunch of HTML on the dom when it fails

Comment: Hi, Lawrence! Actually I don't know much about javascript. If you can show me an example it would be very useful. Thanks!

Comment: Open the network tab, find your AJAX request, see the response that was received; or open it in new tab and see what's happening. A typical JSON response would read something like `{"success": true, "message": "One user yes", "data": 1}` or so. If your server throws an error message, it won't parse as valid JSON, and the process will terminate there, instead of weird output.

Comment: Hi @MarkusAO I don't see errors there it just shows the 1
But when I go to network console I can see a center tag there

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Do I have to add functions.php to auto_prepend_file?

Comment: you're simply getting some error message from ajax request

Comment: @FlashThunder What to do then?

Comment: `console.log(data)` in your `loadUsersOnline()` function and check what's the error in the console

Comment: This is the output:



</center>


1

How can I remove that center

Comment: can you show the contents of `include "../includes/db.php";`? could be in there

Comment: @LawrenceCherone My auto_prepend_file is empy I checked in it in the php.ini

Comment: `
<?php

$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "";
$db['db_name'] = "cms";

foreach($db as $key => $value) {

    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);


?>
`

Comment: cool, is that all of `functions.php` or is there other code in that file?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone
 https://jpst.it/328bv

Comment: My  console.log(status); is success

Comment: dunno, instead of `echo $count_user;` replace with `ob_end_clean();echo $count_user;`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Brooo It worked THANKSSSSSS! You should put this in an answer then I can accept